# Safari: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest

This happens only in Safari.
I create XMLHttpRequest and get console error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 192.168.0.87/cgi/app due to access control checks
```

The strange thing is, that is I try the same thing second time, it goes through. Is there some difference in Safari from Chrome, IE, Edge and Firefox? It is not cross site scripting case, it loads from the same server as the page itself.